# Easy way to draw arc with fixed center but different start and end angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for an easy way to draw an arc that goes e.g. from 45 deg to 90 deg and with 0,0 as center. The arc should start then at (0.707,0.707) and end at (0,1). The common syntax

```
\draw (0,0) arc [radius=1, start angle=45, end angle= 90];
```

always starts the arc at (in this case) (0,0) which makes it hard to draw several arcs with the same center but starting from different angles. 
Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: `\draw (45:1) arc[radius=1, start angle=45, end angle= 90];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want? Notice the black, red and blue arcs with center at `(2,2)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw (45:1) arc[radius=1, start angle=45, end angle= 90];
\draw ([shift={(2,2)}]45:1) arc[radius=1, start angle=45, end angle= 90];
\draw[red] ([shift={(2,2)}]135:1) arc[radius=1, start angle=135, end angle= 270];
\draw[blue] ([shift={(2,2)}]315:1) arc[radius=1, start angle=315, end angle= 360];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For example to get an arc from `50` to `200` with center at `(3,2)` and radius `3`, you could use

```
\draw ([shift={(3,2)}]50:3) arc[radius=3, start angle=50, end angle= 200];
```

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. As expected there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: I want to do same thing with elliptical arc, please help